# What are the double underscores from CakePHP bake?

Tags: php, cakephp

I just started using CakePHP, and am learning how to use Bake. Why does the CRUD is generates have __ when using `$this->Session->setFlash(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));` and what is the true there for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the function used to translate the string passed as argument. Other CMSes / frameworks (also in different programming languages) use a function with similar name.

Answer (score 2):

I believe they're used for localization of a given string.  WordPress does something similar.